# Is there any way to see all the owners from current directory and file name in huge concurrent logs (without ls)

Tags: linux, logfiles, file-ownership

For my current issue I require listing all the files which have a different owner than the current owner. We have almost 600 000 files in current directory and `ls -l` or any other `ls` command will give us trouble.

```
[system@support forms]$ pwd
/u01/system/reports/foms
[system@support forms]$ ls -ltr|more 
total 22066 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 system sys 94208 Feb 5 2016 UTIL_COGS.rdf 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 system sys 417792 Feb 5 2016 UTIL_AL.rdf 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 system sys 212992 Feb 10 2016 UTIL_PE_BATCH.rdf 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 system sys 311296 Feb 10 2016 UTIL_GF.rdf 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dev dev 307200 Feb 10 2016 UTIL_NO_ACCT.rdf >>>> this is my Issue 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 system sys 1101824 Feb 10 2016 UTIL_NO_DETAIL_REPORT.rdf 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dev dev 614400 Feb 16 2016 UTIL_NO301.rdf >>>> this is my Issue
```

What do we need to show the files which do not have the expected owner?

Comment: Try `ls -ltr | grep -v " ${USER} "`. Option `-v` in grep will do inverse match.

Comment: Thanks for your update

Comment: [system@support forms]$ ls -ltr | grep -v "system"
total 134

Comment: Please let me know if those files can see . If I can see those files so fix those files . Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean? It didn't list any files belong to other owners? What is the next processing do you want to perform?

Comment: Yes , it only showing total 134 but not listing anything .

Comment: The output is different with your question i.e. `total 22066`. Make sure you execute the command in correct directory, and if it doesn't give you any output, probably there are no files having other owners. Try `ls -ltr | grep -v "abcdefg" | tail -n 10`. It should list `latest 10 files which owner is not abcdefg`

Comment: Yes , executing it from correct directory . Yes that might be case that no other owners . I will check other servers and update if any issues . Thanks a lot for your quick help and time .

Comment: ls -la should show who the dir is owned by

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` command:

```
 find . ! -user system
```

It will show all files not owned by `system` in the current directory.

You can also choose to see recent files: `-mtime -10` will show only files modified less than 10 days ago.

```
 find . -mtime -10 ! -user system
```

You can also restrict to files only, avoiding to display directories with `-type f`:

```
 find . -mtime -10 -type f ! -user system
```